# How to call struts action from plain javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

This query is related to struts 1.3.

Let's say I have one action called 'getName.do' which is mapped to 'GetName.java' action class. In the `dmexecute` method of this action class, I am setting one result say `String result = Hello;`.

My query is how I can call this struts action (getName.do?parameter=value) from one of my javascript files.

Essentially, I want the value of `result`, which is `Hello`, to be present in my javascript file through this `getName.do?parameter=value` call. How I can make this call in my javascript file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use a JavaScript library for this - one which will do AJAX, such as jQuery or Dojo for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this purpose.

Importing jquery file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Calling action through jquery ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url : "getName.do?parameter=value",
    type : "POST",
    success : function(data) {
        // You'll get your response here
        alert(data);
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @Vinoth : Actually, I need to make the above ajax call from one of my javascript files. Can you please suggest how to include jquery.min.js in my javascript file. ?

Comment: You can include the path in HTML and make sure this file getting loaded before the your javascript file. Like `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myExternalFile.js"></script>`