# How to display names (say John) from database in a table on the same page in java?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

*PS- I have tried using jsp, and the problem I am facing is I am unable to pass the name entered  (ex John) and pass it to the jsp scriptlet.*

**My Current approach:**

From jsp I am calling a javascript function and from there I want to pass the name to database (please note that java script and jsp code are in the same page jsp).

```
<script>
    s=<%=functionCall_To_Jsp_Scriptlet()%>
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: can you put your JSP page code. I think you are not using submit button

Comment: have a look at jquery ajax

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade- you are right, actually currently I am generating the table from js, and to call this js function I have used it as button. 
and if I will use submit button then the table wont get generated. Please do suggest if there is any way.

Comment: The truth is you can't pass value from javascript to java.

Comment: Either you have to submit the form or use Ajax.

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354951/how-to-call-struts-action-from-plain-javascript-file/41357859#41357859). Pass your URL instead of existing URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript runs at client, meaning in browser, and jsp created on the server, so there is no way to have any scriplets available to js, as at the time js will be working, there will be no scriplets on the page at all

If you want to make some calls to the server, you should be using ajax - it allows to send request to server, from which you can access your database and whatever, take a look at pure [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and if you want, you can use much easier [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)(or anything else), but you'l have to include jquery library(or any other) to your page

Comment: OK, that's better

Comment: @DmytroGrynets Thanks a ton for the brilliant and very simple yet concrete ans.